# How to increase variable scope

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

My coffeescript looks like this:

```
initialize = ->
    $.ajax
      url: "map_groups/1.json"
      type: "get"
      dataType: "json"
      success: (response) ->
        console.log response

    mapOptions =
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(response.latitude, response.longitude)
        zoom: 16
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
```

The problem is, `mapOptions` needs to be able to access the ajax response. How can I increase the scope of `response` so that it can be accessed by `mapOptions`?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't move the `mapOptions` code into the `success` handler? It's not just a question of the scope of `response`, it's also a question of timing given that `success` is called asynchronously...

Comment: @nnnnnn I can, but then I will need to access `mapOptions` later. So then I would need to increase the scope of `mapOptions`....

Answer (score 0):

In your `AJAX`

For `success` function, you can have like this,

```
success:function(response) {
           callFunction(response);
        }
```

Your `callFunction` should simply return this `response`, then you can call this function to use in `mapOptions` like

```
mapOptions =
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(response.latitude, response.longitude)
        zoom: 16
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        something:callFunction // your ajax response
```

Comment: I don't think this would work. `something:callFunction` wouldn't get the response, would it? Isn't the response existed on `callFunction()` when you passed it as an argument?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a global variable `global_response`

```
success:function(response) {
    global_response = response
}
```

and then on mapOptions:

```
mapOptions =
center: new google.maps.LatLng(response.latitude, response.longitude)
zoom: 16
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
json_response = global_response
```